# how to change the preferences of eclipse to have a light background and code coloring as default

Tags: eclipse, preferences

i was wondering if there is a solution to set the preferences of eclipse as default because i a friend of mine has change lots of preferences of my eclipse such java code colors and backgound etc and I am used to the ordinary colors of eclipse edit window?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try Window->Preferences->Run/Debug. You can change colors right there, as well as set defaults in any category.

Answer (score 0):

**Preferences -> General -> Appearence -> Colors and Fonts** probably does it for you. There is a button which resets the editor in question:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detail explanation about your question on Eclipse site.

[http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Ffontsandcolors.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/accessibility/fontsandcolors.htm)

Here is the quick answer what exactly you look for. 
Eclipse->Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors (Foreground, background and other appearance colors)